# Session Expired in Laravel Package Development

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

Description
I am using livewire in a laravel package that will plug into a laravel project. I succefully integrated Livewire in my package. The error i am fetching is This page has expired due to inactivty when i click a button that is binded to a component method.
I added csrf token in my base file like

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Exact steps to reproduce

- Create a package inside a laravel project. Just Render a Component
- From Package Route(Follow the normal implementation of livewire).
- Render from packages route file `Route::get('/acc/test'VoucherComponent::class);`
- While Rending template from livewire php
  component make sure to add packagename before the view name like this.
- 

```
public function render(){ 
    return view('acc::livewire.voucher-component')->layout('acc::layouts.app'); 
   }
```

Stripped-down, copy-pastable code snippets
Dependencies

```
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "illuminate/support": "^8.15",
    "livewire/livewire": "^2.3",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0"
```

Browser: [ Chrome,]

Packages Route File

```
    <?php

use Enam\Acc\Http\Livewire\AccHeadComponent;
use Enam\Acc\Http\Livewire\VoucherComponent;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use Enam\Acc\Http\Controllers\HomeController;

Route::get('/acc', function () {
    return view('acc::app');
});
Route::get('/acc/test', VoucherComponent::class);
```

Comment: Does your package route have `web` middleware group applied? Can you share your package's route declaration (file)

Comment: @Donkarnash no i do not have any middleware in my route. its fresh and had only one route.

Comment: @Donkarnash i have edit my question with route file data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try applying `web` middleware to the routes

```php
use Enam\Acc\Http\Livewire\AccHeadComponent; 
use Enam\Acc\Http\Livewire\VoucherComponent; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route; 
use Enam\Acc\Http\Controllers\HomeController; 

Route::middleware(['web'])
->group(function() {
    Route::get('/acc', function () { return view('acc::app'); }); 
    Route::get('/acc/voucher-entry', 'Enam\Acc\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index'); 
    Route::get('/acc/test', VoucherComponent::class);
});
```

Comment: New problem raised named unable to find livewire component as soon as i click the button.

Comment: That was the problem for me. Thank you very much for your help :)